# Stored procedure takes time to fetch data on application layer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have written a stored procedure that talks to around 5 tables.

The performance on database layer looks good. Here is the output.

```
CALL `meetingsReport`('41', '%', '2016-01-01', '2018-01-01');
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 3,288  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 4.203 sec. (+ 0.141 sec. network) */
```

Takes around 4 seconds to generate the report which is fine because the data set is huge, I am performing some pivoting and generate the final data-set.

When I get the data on app level (using laravel php) and calling the procedure as

```
    $params = array($eventId, $status, $startTime, $endTime);
    return DB::select('call meetingsReport( ?,?,?,?)', $params);
```

It takes time, I printed time-stamp to check why is it taking time. Here is the output.

```
12:26:47am - when the route is hit

12:27:00am - when the data is received by procedure call
```

It has taken around 13 seconds. What could be the reason?

**UPDATE:**

I tried with PDO

Here are the details:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=livedb', 'username', 'password');
    $data = $dbh->query("CALL `meetingsReport`('41', '%', '2016-01-01', '2018-01-01') ");
    echo date("h:i:sa")."<br/>";
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
     die();
}
```

and the output is:

```
10:23:22am
10:23:28am
```

It took 6 seconds, I pasted the same code on the framework and the output is:

```
01:15:54am
01:16:06am
```

It takes 12 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `prepare` which is called by `DB::select` which is taking the additional time.

Honestly, you might get better results by creating a report table/view from those 5 large datasets. 
Or look at your indexes on those tables

I've had some remarkable performance increases by simply combining several large tables into a view.

I assume this `DB::select` is only called rarely, otherwise you've got a real issue.